# Wifi signal booster

Tags: windows-vista, software-rec, wireless-networking

Is there any way to get more wifi signal using boosting software on Vista?

Comment: Please i don't need suggestion for hardware , I am looking for the software !!!!

Comment: But there are no software solutions beyond increasing emission power, and that rarely has an effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go hardware instead of software, use a pringles can

http://www.oreillynet.com/cs/weblog/view/wlg/448

Comment: Link is dead now

Answer (score 4):

To get a better signal you would need to have a better wirecard, or an antenna.

Comment: that i know , is there any way to do with software ?

Comment: Try to go in the driver setting of the card. I think you can change some there. I didn't see any improvement but it's worth trying

Comment: You may be able to boost the signal in the properties for the card/driver.  Most the time they are set to 100 percent at the factory any way.  The OS is only involved with the card at the higher levels.  Anything having to do with the radio signal is going to be handled by firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Which WiFi router do you have?

For some of them, you can select the emission power. It's possible on the Linksys WRT54G if you install the DD-WRT firmware (I guess other firmwares for the WRT54G can do this too).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any software that runs on the OS can increase your wifi signal strength.  You need something that runs on the hardware.  If you are trying to increase the signal strength of a wireless router, and your router is one know to work with [Tomato Firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato/) (that page I've linked to lists the routers with which it's know to work), you can use it and see if its wifi Transmit Power configuration option can help you out.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, boosting the power only improves transmission from the router to the device(s). The return signal is not improved, so even doubling the power will give you little to no improvement in range. A better antenna works both ways.

Answer (score 0):

certain wlan controllers used in notebooks have a rather poor reputation (e.g. Ralink), you might look for a quality replacement (e.g. Intel).

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing a directional Helix antenna. it's rather easy to build your self and cheap too. Mostly you can forget about connectors included and just solder it, although dimensions and coiling should be followed as accurately as possible for the antenna to work fluently. There are sites to be found with instructions how to. It's a directional antenna so it should be pointed at a hotspot. You can use a software eg. WirelessMon to help You with the right direction.